# Karate: karate.waitForHttp for url that requires a certificate

Tags: karate

Some of my Karate tests are failing because every now and then there is no connection to the API for whatever reason.

I want it to keep retrying until it gets a connection (up to a limit) - just to make sure it didn't just temporarily drop out.

'retry until' doesn't work as that only comes into effect once the connection has been made.

The other option seems to be: karate.waitForHttp(url)

However, this isn't working as the url I am trying to hit requires an SSL certificate so I get the following error:

```
15:15:08.474 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target, http call failed after 98 milliseconds for url: https://myurl/xxx/xxx/
```

What is the best solution to retry an API for which the connection may have dropped out for a few seconds?